# How to create a while loop for a dice roll in python turtle?

Tags: python, while-loop, python-turtle

I have two turtles set up and the goal of the game is to see which turtle can reach their home first. I have to use a dice roll mechanic to determine this but I do not know how to add one while using a while-loop. Once turtle 1 rolls it is supposed to be turtle 2's turn. They keep doing this until one of the turtles reaches their home. That is when the game ends.

```
import turtle
import random 

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(300,80)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.speed(9)
turtle.circle(30)

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(300,-125)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.speed(9)
turtle.circle(30)

p1 = turtle.Turtle()
p1.shape("turtle")

p2 = turtle.Turtle()
p2.shape("turtle")

def p1_start():
  p1.speed(9)
  p1.penup()
  p1.goto(-200,100)
  p1.pendown()

p1_start()
 
def p2_start():
  p2.speed(9)
  p2.penup()
  p2.goto(-200,-100)
  p2.pendown()

p2_start()

player1 = input("Player 1 enter name: ")
turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(-207, 50)
turtle.write(player1, font=('Arial', 16, 'normal'))
turtle.hideturtle()

player2 = input("\nPlayer 2 enter name: ")
turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(-207, -150)
turtle.write(player2, font=('Arial', 16, 'normal'))
turtle.hideturtle()

player1_color = raw_input("\nPlayer 1 enter color: ")
p1.color(player1_color)

player2_color = raw_input("\nPlayer 2 enter color: ")
p2.color(player2_color)

player1_dict = {"Name": player1, "Color": player1_color}
print("\nPLAYER 1 INFO: ")
print(player1_dict)

player2_dict = {"Name": player2, "Color": player2_color}
print("\nPLAYER 2 INFO: ")
print(player2_dict)

print('\n')

print('Player 1 is now rolling')
roll = int (random.randint (1,6))
if roll==1:
  print('The number on the die is',roll)
elif roll== 2:
  print('The number on the die is',roll)
elif roll == 3:
  print('The number on the die is',roll)
elif roll == 4:
  print('The number on the die is',roll)
elif roll == 5:
  print('The number on the die is',roll)
else: 
  print('The number on the die is',roll)
p1.forward(roll*20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a number of problems: you added too much fine detail before working out big picture issues -- it should be the other way around; you created a data structure to represent your players but in the end you didn't really use it; you designed this for a fixed number of players when you really should have designed it for an unknown (but reasonable) number of players to keep your code honest.

Let's take your code apart and put it back together again to address the above issues:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

NUMBER_PLAYERS = 3
POLE = 300
FONT = ('Arial', 16, 'normal')

players = []

for player in range(1, NUMBER_PLAYERS + 1):
    name = input("\nPlayer " + str(player) + " enter name: ")
    color = input("Player " + str(player) + " enter color: ")

    players.append({'Name': name, 'Color': color})

for number, player in enumerate(players, 1):
    print("\nPlayer", number, "information:", player)

screen = Screen()
height = screen.window_height()
lane_height = height / (NUMBER_PLAYERS + 1)  # divide the vertical space into lanes

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()
marker.speed('fastest')

for number, player in enumerate(players, 1):
    y_coordinate = height/2 - lane_height * number

    marker.penup()
    marker.setpos(-POLE, y_coordinate + 30)
    marker.write(player['Name'], align='center', font=FONT)
    marker.setpos(POLE, y_coordinate - 30)
    marker.pendown()
    marker.circle(30)

    tortoise = Turtle()
    tortoise.hideturtle()
    tortoise.shape('turtle')
    tortoise.speed('slowest')
    tortoise.penup()
    tortoise.goto(-POLE, y_coordinate)
    tortoise.pendown()
    tortoise.color(player['Color'])
    tortoise.showturtle()

    player['Turtle'] = tortoise

while True:
    for number, player in enumerate(players, 1):
        y_coordinate = height/2 - lane_height * number

        print()
        print(player['Name'], 'is now rolling')
        roll = randint(1, 6)
        print('The number on the die is:', roll)
        player['Turtle'].forward(roll * 5)

        if player['Turtle'].distance(POLE, y_coordinate) < 30:
            print()
            print(player['Name'], "is the winner!")
            break

    else:  # no break
        continue

    break  # yes, this is a tricky loop -- take your time with it

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]